# Repeatedly calling a command in a for loop is producing the same output each time in all output files when it is supposed to be randomized

Tags: bash, unix

I'm using a program called Kinfold which produces different output each time I call it. It's possible to generate the same output, but it is very unlikely especially across 10 files.

I'm calling Kinfold in a loop like so:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do echo "GACUAGCUAUCGUCGA" | Kinfold --time=100 --stop > SequenceOverTime/Fold$i.txt; done
```

When I check the last few lines of these files, they're all identical. Furthermore, the entire files are identical.

If I was to write this 10 times:

```
echo "GACUAGCUAUCGUCGA" | Kinfold --time=100 --stop > SequenceOverTime/Fold$i.txt
```

Replacing $i myself with 1 to 10, I'd get different results which is what I want.

Comment: What's the question?  Is it, "Where is the bug in Kinfold?"?

Comment: If you don't write to files, but simply echo the output, do you get the same result every time?

Comment: The results are all still the same without the "> SequenceOverTime/Fold$i.txt" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is Kinfold by any chance seeding its random number generator with the current time? If it is, it may only be using the nearest second and this loop is fast enough that it is being reseeded with the same seed every time.

As an experiment, add a "sleep 2" call at the end of each loop iteration and see if you get better results.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `sleep`, try using the `--seed` option to specify a seed.

Comment: Repeatability is important in science (if this is a sequencing application as I suspect), so you should probably set the seed yourself in any case. Set the seed to $i and you can be sure to get repeatable results.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that Kinfold is setting the random seed from the current time in seconds? If so, and your bash loop is executing Kinfold ten times within one second, you'd get identical results. Try putting a `sleep 3` before (or after) each call to Kinfold in your loop.

Comment: I swear I didn't even see Janne's answer before writing this. Great minds think alike ;)